# Why can I assign a string literal whose length is less than the array itself?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, string-literals

I'm a bit baffled that this is allowed:

```
char num[6] = "a";
```

What is happening here? Am I assigning a pointer to the array or copying the literal values into the array (and therefore I'm able to modify them later)?

Comment: Look at [zero_initialization (3)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: Use a debugger to examine what you have after the assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Why can I assign a string literal less than the array itself? What is happening here?

This is well defined. When [initialize character arrays with string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Character_arrays),

> If the size of the array is specified and it is larger than the number
> of characters in the string literal, the remaining characters are
> zero-initialized.

So,

```
char num[6] = "a";
// equivalent to char num[6] = {'a', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

> 2. Am I assigning a pointer to the array or copying the literal values into the array (and therefore I'm able to modify them later)?

The value will be [copied](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes), i.e. the elements of the array will be initialized by the chars of the string literal (including `'\0'`).

> String literals can be used to initialize character arrays. If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string "foo".
>
> Successive characters of the string literal (which includes the implicit terminating null character) initialize the elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the copy doesn't incur in additional performance penalties at runtime right? Or is it initialized after the stack frame is allocated?

Comment: @Dean It won't. The initialization is same as any other array's initialization.

Answer (score 3):

```
char num[6] = "a";
```

is equivalent to

```
char num[6] = {'a', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I assign a string literal less than the array itself?

This is allowed by the language. It is often useful to be able to add more characters to the array later, which wouldn't be possible if the existing characters filled the entire array.

> Am I assigning a pointer to the array

No. You cannot assign a pointer to an array, so that is not happening.

> or copying the literal values into the array

That is exactly what is happening.

> and therefore I'm able to modify them later

You are able to modify the array, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of declaration is a special syntax sugar thing. It's equivalent to

```
char num[6] = {'a', 0}
```

The array is always modifiable. Its contents after such a declaration would be a character representing `'a'`, a zero (NUL terminator) and the remainder of the array will also be zeroed (zero initialization).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `char num[6] = {"a"};`. It works.

Comment: It doesn't work (RHS is initializer for char[][], LHS is char[]). If you said `char num[6] = {'a'}`, you'd be correct in types and I'm not sure whether the rest is zero-initialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

That is one type of declaration whcih is equivalent to

```
char num[6] = {'a','\0'};
```

You declared c-string with length of max. 5 normal chars, at the end must me \0 to end c - string.

With declaration you can use

```
char num[6] = "a";
```

then you need to assign value:

1. With `strcpy(dest,src)`

   strcpy(num,"test");
2. Char by char

   num[0]='t';
   num[1]='e';
   num[2]='s';
   num[3]='t';
   num[4]='\0';